# Placing Rows of Widgets in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, widget

I'm trying to use my layout file place rows of TextViews and Buttons. It should look something like this:

`Row 1:  [ TextView ( ~2/3 of the screen )      ] [ Button (~1/3 of the screen) ]`

`Row 2: [ TextView ( ~2/3 of the screen ) ] [ Button (~1/3 of the screen) ]`

`Row 3: [ TextView ( ~2/3 of the screen ) ] [ Button (~1/3 of the screen) ]`

`Row 4: [ TextView ( ~2/3 of the screen ) ] [ Button (~1/3 of the screen) ]`

`Row 5: [ TextView ( ~2/3 of the screen ) ] [ Button (~1/3 of the screen) ]`

`.....`

I'm confused as to how to do this. Can I do it with TableLayout or RelativeLayouts? Can someone show me some sample code, as I have no idea how to use XML. Thanks a bunch for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can do that with [LinearLayout - android:weightSum](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android%3aweightSum), here is an example for one row,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="0.1" >

        <TextView
            android:text="left" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="0.33" /> 

        <Button
            android:text="right" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="0.67" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

---

---

**EDIT :**
I see that you didn't understand how to use it, 
let's say you have two layout, (main.xml and list_template.xml)

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    >

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**list_template.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="100" >

        <TextView
            android:text="left" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="33"
            android:id="@+id/list_textView" /> 

        <Button
            android:text="right" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="67" 
            android:id="@+id/list_button" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

list_template is a layout template for one row of list, we will inflate it. How?

```
public class StackoverflowActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        LayoutInflater li =  (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5;  i++){
               View tempView = li.inflate(R.layout.list_template, null);

               TextView list_textView = (TextView) tempView.findViewById(R.id.list_textView);
               list_textView.setText("TextView"+i);

               Button list_button = (Button) tempView.findViewById(R.id.list_button);
               list_button.setText("Button"+i);
               list_button.setId(i);

               list_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Button clicked
                    Toast.makeText(StackoverflowActivity.this, "Button" + v.getId() + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
               mainLayout.addView(tempView);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, this would be your row layout in a ListView.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know what a ListView. Does that mean I'd have multiple LinearLayouts in one whole ListView?